# Получить информацию из LogCat

Tags: android, logcat

```
'08-16 12:52:24.744  1649  2159 D RILJ    : [6475]< RIL_REQUEST_GET_CELL_INFO_LIST....'
```

При просмотре логов через LogCat наткнулся на такую строчку, как через свое приложение можно получить эти данные?

Answer (score 1):

1. Вы можете прочитать логи **своего** приложения, запустив logcat и ловить его output:

   ```
   private String getLogs(){
       StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
       try {
           Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"logcat", "-d", "-v", "threadtime"});

           BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
                   new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));

           String line;
           while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
               builder.append(line);
           }
       } catch (IOException e){
           Log.e("Ooops","Error getting logs");
       }
       return buidler.toString();
   }
   ```

   **N.B.** Это синхронный код, который неплохо бы обернуть в отдельный поток, иначе можно словить ANR.
   Вызов logcat из примера берет текущие логи, возвращает их и завершается. Чтобы получать логи в реальном времени нужно опустить ключ -d и слегка модифицировать код, чтоб строки логов передавать из фонового потока по мере поступления.
2. Вы можете прочитать логи любого приложения, разместив свое приложение в /system/app/ для этого нужен root и разрешение READ_LOGS. Код примерно такой же будет, подозреваю, сам не пробовал.
3. Вы можете попробовать читать логи, запустив adb, в нем logcat через shell см. https://github.com/tananaev/rootless-logcat Нужны дополнительные телодвижения и стабильность работы не гарантируется.

Answer (score 0):

эм немного не понял тебя, но видимо тебе нужен класс Log
и он умеет выводить логи типо Log.d("TAG", "STRING); и пихай туда (это на уровне debug), можно так же вывести Log.e (это на уровне error), и т.д.

Comment: Я имею в виду то, чтобы получить эту строчку из LogCat и дальше обрабатывать ее в своем приложении.